# How to chose vectors such that this Vandermonde-like matrix non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a $6\times 6$ matrix given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_1 &b_1  & a_1^2  & a_1b_1 & b_1^2\\
1 & a_2 &b_2  & a_2^2  & a_2b_2 & b_2^2\\
1 & a_3 &b_3  & a_3^2  & a_3b_3 & b_3^2\\
1 & a_4 &b_4  & a_4^2  & a_4b_4 & b_4^2\\
1 & a_5 &b_5  & a_5^2  & a_5b_5 & b_5^2\\
1 & a_6 &b_6  & a_6^2  & a_6b_6 & b_6^2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
 Suppose $a=(a_1, \dots, a_6)^T$ and $b=(b_1, \dots, b_6)^T$.

How to chose vectors $a,b$ such that the matrix $A$ is nonsingular?

Comment: Your matrix is $5 \times 6$.  Perhaps you want another row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition for it to be nonsingular is of course that its determinant is nonzero.
That determinant is a rather nasty polynomial in the $a_i$ and $b_i$, irreducible over the rationals, with $720$ terms, each of total degree $8$.

Of course a necessary condition is that the ordered pairs $(a_i, b_i)$ are all distinct.

One sufficient condition is that the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: Could you please explain the sufficient condition?which is $a$ and $b$ are algebraically independent imply $A$ is nonsingular

Comment: I mean the whole set $\{a_1, \ldots, a_6, b_1, \ldots, b_6\}$ algebraically independent.  This says that any polynomial in the $a_i$ and $b_i$ with rational coefficients, not all $0$, has a nonzero value.  The determinant is such a polynomial.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that if $a_1, \ldots, a_6,b_1, \ldots, b_6$ are a random sample from any continuous probability distribution, this condition will be true with probability $1$.